# Flutter Dependency Error (flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

When I try to add flutter_svg dependency to add SVG format picture in my project it throws me an error like that:
[image]

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.19.2+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:57:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
```

I'm using flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-18.0.pre.193). and flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1

I've also with a lower version of this dependency, but still the same error.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, and the actual code is already .maybeOf().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **flutter_svg** didn't migrate to [nullsafety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide), try switch to stable channel and repair cache files.

```
1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub cache repair 
4. flutter packages get
5. flutter run
```

If this does not help then try this
https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/479

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

add the following dependency

> flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3

instead of

> flutter_svg: ^0.19.2+1

Then follow these steps

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this was an issue for me when I was working on the master branch for a recent project. It was an issue which only came up for the flutter internalisation package.

The main issue is with the **intl** package:
https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install

To fix this, below the dependencies, please add another section, that will override the **intl** dependency, which is being pulled by the **flutter_localizations** package:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

It should now work for the **master** branch. Another tip, you should avoid working on the **master** branch, because **master** changes all the time. You should stick to either **stable** or **beta**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But still the same problem. 

Answer (score 0):

I am using **flutter beta version** as I am using beta to develop my website, this issue also came to me today, I solved it by running this command,

```
flutter downgrade
```

Comment: have u ever faced this error ?  there is no prevously recorded versuon channel beta

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by delete  nullOk: true from this line because Localizations.localeOf take context only as a parameter

```
locale:
    context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context) : null,
```

instead of

```
locale:
    context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
```

or you can change your channel from master channel to stable channel by using this command line on your terminal.

flutter channel stable
flutter clean